# how do i conditionally delete specific value in specific array with jq?

Tags: json, jq

This is my JSON data input:

```json
[
  {
    "creator": "M.W. Seo",
    "co_author": [
      "H.W. Lee",
      "S.H. Jeon",
      "M.W. Seo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "creator": "Jeffrey A. Laman",
    "co_author": [
      "Jeffrey A. Laman",
      "Mike",
      "Jackson"
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my desired JSON data output:

```json
[
  {
    "creator": "M.W. Seo",
    "co_author": [
      "H.W. Lee",
      "S.H. Jeon"
    ]
  },
  {
    "creator": "Jeffrey A. Laman",
    "co_author": [
      "Mike",
      "Jackson"
    ]
  }
]
```

What I have tried but is not working:

```sh
jq '.[:2]| map(if .co_author[] == .creator then del(.co_author[])' test_4.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtract `.creator` directly from the array in `.co_author` and apply this to all elements of the top-level array using `map`:

```sh
jq 'map(.co_author -= [.creator])' test_4.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "creator": "M.W. Seo",
    "co_author": [
      "H.W. Lee",
      "S.H. Jeon"
    ]
  },
  {
    "creator": "Jeffrey A. Laman",
    "co_author": [
      "Mike",
      "Jackson"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Jkh3gWBH2m)